# New onvif events wsdl still not fixed?

Tags: c#, wsdl, svcutil.exe, onvif

To retrieve events from ONVIF compliant devices you need to use the ONVIF events wsdl.

The following is mentioned on the [ONVIF FAQ & Support page](http://developer.onvif.org/pub/info/Technical_FAQ.html):

> Visual Studio 2008, 2010 and 2012 generate web services clients for the WCF framework with a tool called svcutil.exe. This tool has an issue by mapping port types to interfaces and complex types to classes. When an wsdl file contains a port type and complex type with same name this results in a name clash at compile time like "The namespace 'foo.Event' already contains a definition for 'CreatePullPoint' ".

As a workaround they edited the events.wsdl to use a modified ws base notification file that's available via [this](http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/event/wsdl/event-vs.wsdl) link.

however, when I add the wsdl file to my solution I get an error saying that the file mentioned in the following line in the wsdl file cannot be found

```
<wsdl:import namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/bw-2" location="bw-2-vs-mod.wsdl"/>  <!-- Use modified OASIS file to avoid svcutil name clash -->
```

when I browse to http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/ and manually look for the file I can see it's not listed there either. Is there another location where the file is located?

Comment: I don't know where the file may be, however, are you able to modify the original and fix it yourself? If it is only a single name clash, it may not be that hard to make the same fix. Obviously change the location pointed to in events.wsdl too.

Comment: I tried to modify the original .wsdl file but I did not succeed in getting a working wsdl afterwards.

Comment: your file "bw-2-vs-mod.wsdl" is relative to the path gived by the link, therefore the absolute path is http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/event/wsdl/bw-2-vs-mod.wsdl .

Answer (score 2):

The WSDL link provided [here](http://developer.onvif.org/pub/info/Technical_FAQ.html) is incorrect and is missing a character. The correct URL is http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/events/wsdl/event-vs.wsdl. Using this URL resolved the namespace error for me.